# WCF service application and wcf service library

Tags: wcf

i know it's been asked, but i want to clear things out, what is the difference between WCF service application and wcf service library, and how can i connect them to other machine?

is Wcf SA need to host on IIS? or is it the SL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A service application includes a website host already setup for you. A service library is a library of services that a host can reference and startup.

If you start with a service library (recommended) you can then choose any host you wish (a windows service, IIS/ASP.NET, or even a console application) and you'd just reference your library from your new host. Choosing a Service Application limits your host to just IIS/ASP.NET (though this might be ok for your purposes, but will limit the protocols you can use).

Comment: It's important to note - because I see this frequently on SO - that the `system.serviceModel` section of the app.config from the library project needs to be included in the app/web.config of the hosting application.

Comment: i want to create a service that can communicate through internet, but without website, how can i achieve this? do i have to use SA or SL? sorry. is SA and SL can communicate through internet?

Comment: @Dakoy - you would use a WCF Service Library, and then you would host it in Windows Service or a console app (or some other form of self-hosting), and that application would reference your WCF service library.

Comment: is SL can be host on IIS? can i get my my service trhough internet without website? just IIS or what? sorry i really need help on this, thanks.